# Alter JvLoginDialog's caption

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe4, jvcl

(JVCL - JEDI) Is it possible to change the caption on JvLoginDialog1 that says "type your user name and password to enter the application" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume you're talking about the "hint label", instead of the `Caption` which you can change in OI. You can modify/localize `RsHintLabel` resource string in 'jvresources.pas' for that. Also see other entries under the heading 'JvLoginForm.pas' in the same unit.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't want to change the original source code (last change: 2004!) because it would get lost on reinstallation. So I cheated:

```
class procedure TFormMain.ApplicationOnModalBegin(Sender: TObject);
begin
  with Application do
    if Components[ComponentCount - 1] is TJvLoginForm then
      (Components[ComponentCount - 1] as TJvLoginForm).OnFormShow:= JvLoginFormShow;
end;

class procedure TFormMain.JvLoginFormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
  (Sender as TJvLoginForm).HintLabel.Caption:= 'my hint';
end;
```

Note: TJvLoginDialog has an OnShow event, it just doesn't work. It would make it a lot easier to customize the dialog. I did not test it, but I guess the fix could be in `function TJvLoginDialog.DoLogin`: add `OnFormShow:= Self.OnShow;`.

Comment: Does it always have to be the last component?

Comment: I guessed so - the form is always newly created directly before it becomes modal. So it should be at the end of the list - or not? @SertacAkyuz

Comment: Probably. Still iterating through the components might be safer. Or not? ... ;)